# Connecting Young's Inequality for Increasing Functions w/Young's Inequality for Conjugate Holder Exponents

Tags: analysis, young-inequality

From the Wikipedia page on [Young's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products):

> [image]

This above statement of Young's Inequality is the most frequent one that I've encountered in textbooks. Yet consider:

> [image]
>
> [image]

This second version of Young's Inequality for increasing functions has a very nice, intuitive visual proof (shown above).

**Problem:** What is connecting Young's Inequality for increasing functions to Young's Inequality for conjugate Holder exponents? In particular, is there a way to prove that

$$
ab \le {a^p \over p} + {b^q \over q}
$$

using the proof involving increasing functions, shown visually above?

Comment: The answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1132153/16490 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2253569/16490 prove this inequality, but none of them seem to use Young's inequality to do so...

Comment: Yes, the function $f(x) = x^{p-1}$ is precisely an example of a continuous increasing function with $f(0)=0$, and its inverse is perhaps amusingly $f^{-1}(x)=x^{q-1}$.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149901/geometric-interpretation-of-youngs-inequality?rq=1

Comment: exponent calculation: $1/p + 1/q = 1$ so $q+p=qp$ so $p=q(p-1)$ and $q=p(q-1)$, so that 
$$ \frac1{p-1} = \frac qp = q-1$$

Comment: @ziggurism sorry it was Arnaud's link that has the picture

Comment: Interesting. So this inequality is a generalization of Young's inequality, not an equivalent statement.